# I'm getting java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException when I run the code given below

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to insert a very long String which is basically a base64-encoded string for image ,into a CLOB-type column in the database.But I'm getting the exception java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException . What is the right way to do this?

I've tried both Clob object in setClob() and reader object in setClob(),but gives the same exception "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException", also I've updated the ojdbc14.jar to ojdbc6.jar as previously it was giving "java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CPreparedStatement.setClob(ILjava/io/Reader;)" .

```
       String uid = (String)session.getAttribute("uid");
        String userPhoto = request.getParameter("userPhoto");
        String AadhaarImageURI = request.getParameter("AadhaarImageURI");
        System.out.println(uid+"\n"+userPhoto+"\n"+AadhaarImageURI);
        //StringReader reader1 = new StringReader(userPhoto);
        //StringReader reader2 = new StringReader(AadhaarImageURI);

 try {

          Connection con = Connect_db.getCon();
          PreparedStatement ps= con.prepareStatement("update aadhardb set userimg=?, aadharimg=?, where u_id=?");


       Clob myclob = con.createClob();
       myclob.setString(1, userPhoto);
       Clob myclob2 = con.createClob();
       myclob2.setString(1,AadhaarImageURI);

           ps.setClob(1,myclob);
           ps.setClob(2,myclob2);
           ps.setString(3,uid);

       ps.execute();

           con.close();


}

         catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace(); }
```

I want to update the CLOB columns with the Strings(>4000).

Here is the complete stack trace.

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:953)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1222)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3488)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1374)
at org.apache.jsp.userAadhaarEntry_jsp._jspService(userAadhaarEntry_jsp.java:141)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Post the complete and exact exception stack trace: it telle what and where the problem is.

Comment: Tell me I'm right, it was just a comma!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be a comma before WHERE

```
      PreparedStatement ps= con.prepareStatement("update aadhardb set userimg=?, aadharimg=? where u_id=?");
```

I've learned that one the hard way before.